I have a question regarding Infineon Smart Cards that support SCP03 Protocol
For the sample Infineon card I have, when I provide FIXED_HOST_CHALLENGE = "67917EAE48AF74D3"; to the INS_INITIALIZE_UPDATE APDU command, my subsequent INS_EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE APDU succeeds (status 0x9000). (SCP03 protocol)
Whereas when I randomly generate the _hostChallenge (as shown below)
        _hostChallenge = new byte[8];
        RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        rng.GetBytes(_hostChallenge);

and feed that to INS_INITIALIZE_UPDATE APDU command, my subsequent INS_EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE APDU fails.
Any clue as to why this might happen? (Of course for production purposes we have to use randomly generated host challenges). Thanks
I expect successful handshake for randomly generated host challenges.
